# Median value doesn't exist in the input list?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have something weird going on, I am attempting to find the median colour in a numpy array. If I work in the BGR/RGB colour space then I find the correct median. If I work in the LUV colour space then I get an incorrect median and the median colour found doesn't even exist in the input list.

Why do I get a different/incorrect median when working in the LUV colour space?

Below shows the median I have found when working in BGR (left), the median when working in LUV (middle) and the input/src image (right):

[image]

That brown colour (middle) is the LUV median converted to BGR. There is no brown in the image though?

Below is my code and the original src image:

```
bgr = cv2.imread('../../images/red_blue_ex.png')
bgr_median = np.median(bgr, axis=(0,1))
swatch = np.full((25,25,3), bgr_median, dtype='uint8')
cv2.imshow('bgr_median', swatch)

luv = cv2.imread('../../images/red_blue_ex.png')
luv = cv2.cvtColor(luv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
luv_median = np.median(luv, axis=(0,1))
swatch = np.full((25,25,3), luv_median, dtype='uint8')
swatch = cv2.cvtColor(swatch, cv2.COLOR_LUV2BGR) 
cv2.imshow('luv_median', swatch)

cv2.imshow('src', bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV), BGR/RGB conversion to LUV is non-linear...this means the median can be different from one space to antoher